# Python - How do I print all method docstrings in a package

Tags: python

I have a project with several modules.  Each module has several classes and each class has several methods.  In this case, the methods are features of a data model.  Is it possible to document the model by recursively stepping through each of the modules, classes and methods to grab all the docstrings?

We will be adding to the features list in the future and it would be great if we could update the documentation on the fly rather than keep some manual list.  My hope was to use pandas to create a nice spreadsheet with module name, class name, method name and docstring for each method in the program.  I have worked on a few solutions, but can't seem to land on something that gathers all the requirements and doesn't require a static list of module/class names to begin with (I.e.import).

Working g with Python 2.7 in a Windows environment.

Thanks in advance.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This site exists to help you fix your code, not to write it for you. The general approach would be to iterate over the names in `dir(cls)` to determine which are callable. For those that are, print out their `__doc__` attribute. However there are solutions (many of them mentioned in https://wiki.python.org/moin/DocumentationTools) that will essentially do this already - they are open source, so you can read their code!